# How can I kill Kerbals? From what drop height can they not survive?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

What are all the ways a Kerbal in KSP might die? I know that they always wear space suits, so they (seemingly) can't suffocate.

Side Question: How far must a Kerbal fall to die?

Comment: @fredley You changed the title to make me sound murderous!

Comment: [murder](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2187/the-memes-of-arqade-and-its-chat/2190#2190) is kind of a *thing* around here...

Comment: I do not approve of such a thing! (but then again, I guess this makes the title more interesting XD)

Comment: Kerbals can die from either small hops, yet survive very high falls. [True story](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YOjY1pl_iW8&list=UU8DIKwGU8wFZfk3Xi3-zcrQ).

Comment: It's not the fall that kills y'all, it's the ---sudden stop at the end--- speed you're going.  Also, [related (if not dupe)](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/98272/how-fast-do-i-need-to-be-going-to-kill-my-kerbals)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Kerbals are a very weak species and will die quite easily. I find that 50m is usually a sure death.  They can also die from an explosion of the command part (which varying on the part can withstand different blasts).

Comment: 50 meters is 15 floors... I don't think you'd find many humans that could survive that...

Comment: Of course there are plugins like Deadly Reentry - for EVA kerbal it's really really nice - pufff, no kerbal, just small cloud of smoke :D

Comment: @Coomie Then again, they're not human...

Comment: It's not the fall that kills you; it's the sudden stop at the bottom. OR to rephrase: it's not the height. Your Kerbal can step out of a speeding capsule at 1m, and not make it.

Comment: Of course, I've know kerbals dropped from orbit around Kerbal to survive.

Comment: @WillihamTotland: Do you mean Kerbin (planet) or Kerbol (sun)?

Comment: @Joshua Onto Kerbin, critically, but beyond that, either.

Comment: @Coomie: The [square cube law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square%E2%80%93cube_law) applies here (both for terminal velocity and impact resistance). If you drop an ant from a height of 15 ant floors, it'll be fine. Kerbals are smaller than humasn and thus more able to survive falls; and that's assuming that Kerbals aren't even naturally sturdier. Given the haphazard nature of their engineering, it's likely that natural selection has made them hardier than the average human.

Answer (score 2):

I found the Kerbals to be both flimsy and durable depending on the situation.

Command module falling over: Kerbal dies in the explosion, despite the fall of the module not being that great to begin with, just enough to break the module.

Reentry: This happened not long after starting the game... I decided to try an EVA with jebediah, not realizing that i wasn't in a full orbit. As soon as a realized that i was on my way down, fast, without any means of getting back to the plummeting ship, i proceeded to fire the EVA suit at full, hoping that i could slow down and come to a nice landing. Of course the EVA thrust wasn't big enough, but it turned out that the EVA suit and the drag combined slowed me down enough to actually have Jebediah survive a fall from 90km. The landing looked painful as he bounced off the ground, but BadS as he is, he just stood up afterwards, grinning, awaiting recovery.

Construction accident: A kerbal fell down from the top of a 12-stage rocket ready to launch. Hit a few parts on the way down, and faceplanted into the ground. Coworkers were unable to revive him, and his life insurance now pays for the R&D departments coffee-consumption.

Comment: I think Kerbals might be a lot more flimsy than they were in earlier versions. I've repeatedly killed them quite easily just using the puff-pack to cover distance on the surface of the Mun and landing too hard.